# WshShell Run Without Waiting But Exec for Status Update (run vs exec issue)

Tags: javascript, windows, exec, wsh

Launching a script via JS in a Windows environment.

I need 2 things:

1. No pop-up window (ie. `shell.run(cmd, 0)`)
2. I can't wait around for thread to finish (ie. `shell.exec()` or `shell.run(cmd, 0, false)`)

So what do I do?  These seem mutually exclusive.  I can't wait for it to finish but I will poll its status to see when it finishes.  Obviously exec lends itself better to this as it contains the status and such...though I need to do away with the pop-up command windows, as there can be many with this system..

Anybody know what I can do?  I'll be polling anyway, but without waiting around for the process to finish, run will return 0 immediately, and I'll have no idea if it's finished other than trying to find the image name in the process list...but I don't like doing this without the PID, I rather not rely on name.

Ideal would be exec but hiding command window...but from what I can tell this isn't possible...

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the executable using the Win32_Process WMI class to get its process id. After this you can query WMI to tell if the process is still running. Example:

```
var SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7;

var WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!root/CIMV2");

function processExists(processId) {
  var processColl = new Enumerator(WMI.ExecQuery("select ProcessId " +
    "from Win32_Process where ProcessId=" + processId.toString()));
  return ! processColl.atEnd();
}

var startInfo = WMI.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup").SpawnInstance_();
startInfo.ShowWindow = SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE;

var process = WMI.Get("Win32_Process");
var method = process.Methods_.Item("Create");
var inParams = method.InParameters.SpawnInstance_();
inParams.CommandLine = "cmd.exe";
inParams.CurrentDirectory = null;
inParams.ProcessStartupInformation = startInfo;

var outParams = process.ExecMethod_(method.Name, inParams);
if ( outParams.ReturnValue == 0 ) {
  var processId = outParams.ProcessId;
  WScript.Echo("ProcessId: " + processId.toString());
} else {
  WScript.Echo("ReturnValue: " + outParams.ReturnValue);
  WScript.Quit(outParams.ReturnValue);
}

while ( processExists(processId) ) {
  WScript.Echo("Process still running");
  WScript.Sleep(1000);
}
```